# Issue in Observable vs Promised-based Approach

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

In my Ionic/Angular app I am converting some promised-based implementations to use observables instead. I am running into one issue with a particular function. My original (working, promised-based) code looked like this:

```
  async getPlayerStats() {
    this.user = await this.mainService.getPlayerStats(this.username);
    this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus();
  }
```

As you can see, with the above implantation I am waiting on `this.user` before calling `this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus();` That's important because I use `this.user` in a `for-loop` in that function.

Now, in my new observable-based implementation, my `getPlayerStats()` function looks like this:

```
  getPlayerStats() {
    this.mainService.getPlayerStats(this.username).subscribe(
      user => this.user = user,
      error => this.errorMsg = error,
    );
    this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus();
  }
```

The problem here is that `this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus()` fires before `this.user` is available. So my question is, how do I change this function above here so that I am assured I have `this.user` data *before* `this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus()` is called? Do I call it from somewhere within the `subscribe()` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `this.mainService.getPlayerStats(this.username)` returns an observable, you need to include all the statements directly dependent on this observable inside the subscription. Try the following

```js
getPlayerStats() {
  this.mainService.getPlayerStats(this.username).subscribe(
    user => { 
      this.user = user;            // <-- this is assigned asynchronously
      this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus();
    },
    error => this.errorMsg = error,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I call it from somewhere within the subscribe() block?

Yes, like so.

```
getPlayerStats() {
  this.mainService.getPlayerStats(this.username).subscribe(
    user => {
         this.user = user;
         this.checkRookieTopicCompletionStatus();
      }
    error => this.errorMsg = error,
  );
}
```